# Getting fewer outputs than inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve "Bad Prices" on Codeforces. The problem asks you to find the number of integers in the array, such that there is a smaller integer after them in the array. Here's a sample test:

```
5
6
3 9 4 6 7 5
1
1000000
2
2 1
10
31 41 59 26 53 58 97 93 23 84
7
3 2 1 2 3 4 5
```

The first number is the number of test cases, the following are the testcases, consisting of the length of the array and the array itself.
Here's my code:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
  count=0
  a=input()
  x=input().split(' ')
  for i in x:
      for j in x[x.index(i):]:
          if int(i)>int(j):
              count+=1
  if count%2==0:
      print(int(count/2))
  else:
      print(int(count))
  count=0
  x=[]
```

For some reason, the code works, but only for 4 of 5 test cases, completely ignoring the last one. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please add a description of what the code is supposed to do to your question.

Comment: What's `a` supposed to be for?  It looks like it's unused.

Comment: `x.index()` will not do the right thing if some numbers appear multiple times.  ... And that's exactly what is causing your problem.  You should use `for n,i in enumerate(x):` to get both the index of and the value of each item.

Comment: Is this the problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1213/B?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem

Comment: Can't you just do this as `(lambda x=list(map(int, input().split())): sum(any(w < v for w in x[i+1:]) for i, v in enumerate(x)))()`?

Answer (score 1):

1. for j in x[x.index(i):]:

index() function always gives you the first occurrence.
Ex: array is 2 1 3 2 4 5 6
x.index(2)=0,x.index(1)=1,x.index(3)=2,x.index(2)=0,x.index(4)=4,x.index(5)=5,
x.index(6)=6.
Though there are multiple occurrences of 2, the index() functions cosiders the first occurrence always.                                                                                       So,When i=2(index=3), j iterates from the index(0) to index(6) and not from index(3) to index(6).
To overcome this you can make use of variable a(length of the array) and change it like this:

```
for i in range(int(a)):
      for j in range(i,int(a)):
          if int(x[i])>int(x[j]):
              count+=1
```

2. if count%2==0:
   print(int(count/2))
   else:
   print(int(count))

These conditions are not necessary.
If you find an element that is smaller than the current element u can increase the count and break from the inner loop and continue the process for the next element.
After the count+=1, you can add a break statement.
Replace the if, else condition with a print(count) statement.

3.
Initializing the count variable with zero at the beginning of a new test case is enough, no need to do it twice. Initializing x=[] will make no difference because the existing data will be overridden when you assign new data to the variable x[]

Answer (score 0):

Tim Roberts identified the issue in the comments, the problem is your use of the `index` method.  As he suggested, using the index generated from`enumerate` will allow you to avoid that issue.

Note, slices are not indices, so whereas `[cur_index + 1]` may be an invalid index, `[cur_index + 1:]` is always a valid slice even though it may be an empty one.

Example:

```
num_sets = int(input())
for _ in range(num_sets):
    _ = input()
    prices_per_day_str = input()
    prices_per_day = list(map(int, prices_per_day_str.split()))

    bad_price_count = 0
    for cur_index, cur_price in enumerate(prices_per_day):
        for future_price in prices_per_day[cur_index + 1:]:
            if cur_price > future_price:
                bad_price_count += 1
                break

    print(bad_price_count)
```